# Parse JSON from external source

Tags: javascript, json

Is there any possible way to get json file from other url.
I Want to parse  this url to my website http://cricapi.com/api/cricket?apikey=TESTKEY0273.

Comment: You're looking to do a "cross-domain" resource request-- you're going to want to google "jsonp" I think-- note that this must be supported by the domain that you're requesting from.

Comment: use get method of jquery or ajax

Comment: Depends on the server. Does it have CORS enabled or does it provide JSONP?

Comment: you can help with any method @azad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can hit the API Directly** . No need to make jsonp requests. The domain already have **`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`** header means you can directly interact with API from any domain. There will be no cross-domain issues involved.

This is plain JavaScript solution. If you are using jQuery you can use `$.get` or `$.ajax` functions directly.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://cricapi.com/api/cricket?apikey=TESTKEY0273", true);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var dataRec = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      showData(dataRec);
    } else {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  console.error(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.send(null);

function showData(list){
   list.data.forEach(function(v){
   
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.style.border = "1px solid";
   div.style.padding = "10px";
   var span = document.createElement('span');
   span.innerText = "Title : " + v.title;
   div.appendChild(span);
   var elem = document.getElementById("match");
   elem.appendChild(div);
   
   });
}
```

```html
<div id="match">
Matchs : 


</div>
```

Comment: can you parse in html

Comment: @AkashMalviya updated to insert html. I have published title.. you can make entries for other items similarly as well.

Comment: Thanks Atul for your help and kind gesture

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery you can use the method [`getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

```js
$.getJSON("https://cricapi.com/api/cricket?apikey=TESTKEY0273",
  function(data) {

    data.data.forEach(function(item) {
      for (var key in item) {
        $("#content").append($("<div />").append("<span>" + key + ": </span>").append(item[key]));
      }
      $("#content").append("<hr />");
    });
  });
```

```css
#content>div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#content span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: What makes you think the OP is using jQuery?

Comment: @FelixKling, it's an option.

Comment: can you parse as innerhtml